# Partially hidden Jupyter notebook cells

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Jupyter Notebook cells are partially hidden. I have never seen this happen in years of using notebooks and writing code. Does anyone know a fix?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1560) helps, they recommendo to reopen your tab.